# Console (CMD like) in a DirectX application

Tags: 3d, directx11, c++, winapi

I really need a console for the game i'm making. I am programming a first person camera right now and i want to see what is going on with the variables (to be more specific i need to know if i'm getting the mouse input as i want or no) and i don't know how to see it. I searched online A LOT and i found tons of scripts with no explanation so i don't know what to do.
What i need is the "noob" line of command you get when you don't use WINAPI. The one you have from just writing your code into the dev c++.
I know it sounds like i have no idea of what i'm saying but i don't know how to ekplain it better.

Comment: So do you need to have the console in-game or would just the default Windows CMD do the job? Do you need input or is output enough?

Comment: Or, would it be sufficient to output data to your Visual Studio console?

Comment: Tyyppi_77 no i don't need it in-game, i just need the default windows CMD, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to just use [`OutputDebugString`](https://www.google.fi/search?q=Output+DebugString&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=gYWgWO2PJtiDZPi3tmg) which outputs to Visual Studio's Output-window.

If you want a Windows-style CMD instead, [this  SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24399334/3450269) seems to create one for you.

Comment: I already found that code and it doesn't work! I don't know why but i just can't printf() nothing on the cmd

Answer (score 1):

I want to provide an alternative way to achieve both a console and a Window to draw your graphics to. Configure your project to be a default console project and create the window manually through the WinAPI. This way you have both a console and a window to draw your graphics to. If you later decide you do not need the console anymore you can do

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
```

at the beginning of your program and the console wont show up anymore.

There are many Window libraries for C++ on Windows, but it is also easy to roll your own Window class, which supports all the features you need.

Comment: LukeG i will try this as soon as i can, thanks a lot, this seems great!

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this. You could have a class like...

```
class Console
{
private:
    /*
     * Stores each line inputted to render later.
     */
    std::list<std::string> lines;
public:
    /*
     * Check the syntax of the inputted line, execute if valid, and add it to the list of lines.
     * Return true if the syntax was valid.
     */
    bool processCmd(const std::string& line);
}
```

But that example is very elementary. Check out the Quake source, that may be a good learning point.

On the rendering end, you need to temporarily render in 2d, so you can draw the console, then switch back to 3d.

**EDIT 1:**

For parsing you could use `boost::program_options`. There are some other libraries too, for example (quick Googpe search):
http://optionparser.sourceforge.net/
https://github.com/FlorianRappl/CmdParser
https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts

These are designed to parse the CLI, but can be used for your task.

Comment: Oliver Yasuna thanks, i will check out the quake source for more infos

Comment: Glad to help. Hope you figure it out!

Comment: You said in a comment above that `printf()` doesn't work?

Comment: Check out my edit for more information